# PL/SQL 103 error when Compiling the date calculat formula

Tags: formbuilder

select months_between ('sysdate',to_date (':date_of_birth' , 'dd/MM/yyyy'))/12 from dual;[image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ66c.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. Then update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go through below correct.

select months_between (sysdate,to_date ('01/01/1980' , 'dd/MM/yyyy'))/12 from dual;

--Output

40.46864882019115890083632019115890083633

It seems sysdate passed under singlequotes and causing value numeric error.